# How do I get the man command?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Windows Subsystem for Linux for the first time and downloaded the Debian distribution from the Windows Store.

The first thing I tried to do was use the "mv" command. The second thing was to run "man mv" because I don't remember how to use it. But I received the error:

```
-bash: man: command not found
```

It *looks* like the package I want is called manpages. But I can't install that:

```
sudo apt-get install manpages
[sudo] password for pi:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package manpages is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'manpages' has no installation candidate
```

How do I get the man command up and running?

Comment: `apt install man-db`?

Comment: E: Unable to locate package man-db

Comment: Try `apt update` and then the commands.

Comment: Tried with both "apt-get" and "apt". Is there a difference?

Comment: `apt` is the newer version of `apt-get`.

Comment: That did it! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`apt update` to update the local package lists followed by `apt install man-db` to install the actual package.

Comment: Thanks! How does `apt update` make the man-db package visible?

Comment: `apt update` gets the latest versions of all packages.

Answer (score 7):

I want to add to elken's answer that apparently, the 'man-db' packages doesn't cover all the manpages. For example, I needed documentation for the C stdio library (fopen, fgets, ...), and for that I had to install 'manpages-dev':

```
sudo apt install manpages-dev
```

Apparently there are also some other manpage collections (/different names for them on certain unix distros), see https://superuser.com/questions/40609/how-to-install-man-pages-for-c-standard-library-functions-in-ubuntu